# How to resize and redraw UITextView on UIScrollView zoom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` hierarchy like this `UIScrollView` -> `DrawingView(UIView)` -> `UITextView`. When I zoom `UIScrollView`, it also scaling the `UITextView` causing blurred text and big font. I need the same resize frame of `UITextView` but it should not get blurred and at proper font.

Showing in images what i exactly need.

Before zoom my UITextView should look like :

[image]

When I zoom, its looking like this :

[image]

This is an image where I want `UITextView` should look like when I zoom/ or max zoom level.

[image]

Here is my code, Tried each 'TRY' code once but none works.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.drawingView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    // TRY 1
    self.textView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.textView.frame.size.width*scale, self.textView.frame.size.height*scale);

    // TRY 2
    scale *= [[[scrollView window] screen] scale];
    self.textView.contentScaleFactor = scale;

    // TRY 3
    CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width * scale;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height * scale;
    self.textView.frame = frame;
    self.textView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    // TRY 4
    self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale);

    // TRY 5
    scaleTracker *= scale;
    [self.drawingView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
    self.drawingView.frame = CGRectMake((int)self.drawingView.frame.origin.x,
                              (int)self.drawingView.frame.origin.y,
                              (int)(self.drawingView.frame.size.width * scaleTracker),
                              (int)(self.drawingView.frame.size.height * scaleTracker));

    NSLog(@"TextView Frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.textView.frame));
    NSLog(@"DrawingView Frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.drawingView.frame));
}
```

Comment: Why do you have DrawingView as the contents view? Do you draw something there? If yes - do you need to redraw it too?

Comment: @yurish, i need drawingView for drawing and also need to redraw it.

Comment: my bad - i deleted my answer - it works for labels, but not textfields.

Comment: My thought would be to change the text font size on scrollviewDidScroll.  Base the new text font on the scrollview `zoomScale` property.  Sometimes this `zoomScale` property returns 1 even though you are zoomed in or out, need to deal with that properly.

Answer (score 0):

deal with UITextView zoom  you can do this:

```
    //scale :zoomScale
    for (UIView *subView in self.txtContent.subviews) {
        subView.contentScaleFactor = scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }
```